# Delete directories with xargs

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, xargs

I've got a list of folders I want to remove using `xargs` generated using `find`

#### `find` command

```
$ find /home/users/lukes -maxdepth 1 -type d > test.txt
```

#### test.txt

```
/home/users/lukes/2
/home/users/lukes/6
/home/users/lukes/7
/home/users/lukes/3
/home/users/lukes/1
/home/users/lukes/4
/home/users/lukes/5
```

#### command and --verbose output

```
$ xargs --verbose -0 -I{} rm -rfv {} < test.txt 
rm -rfv /home/users/lukes/2
/home/users/lukes/6
/home/users/lukes/7
/home/users/lukes/jadu_package_1.1.0
/home/users/lukes/3
/home/users/lukes/1
/home/users/lukes/4
/home/users/lukes/5
```

But the directories don't get removed ?

I'm using `-0` as there could be whitespace when I run this for real, I'm generating the list so I can confirm every line is safe to be deleted in the text file rather than piping `find` directly to `xargs`

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let me start by saying I have a supreme dislike of xargs. It can be really dangerous if you are not careful. That being said, something like this would work:

```
find /home/users/luke -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d|xargs --verbose -I{} rm -vfr "{}"
```

By throwing {} in double quotes, you remove any issues involving spaces. I tend to use `""` or `''` around stuff like that as often as possible. I put mindepth on there to ensure it does not include the parent folder, as some OS's have maxdepth include the parent directory (ie '.') which would effectively nuke the entire folder. I assume you don't want that.

Again, be VERY careful with xargs. That command can be evil. I would say add -0 on it first to have it show what will be run, then remove -0 once you are really sure.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I mentioned I can't pipe directly from find due to needing to vet each directory for deletion - will this work with the text.txt file as input ? also as part of vetting I removed . (current directory) from list

Comment: confirmed you can use text.txt as input